# Find minimum value in 2nd column of month in first column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

Column A: dates,
Column B: values

I need to find the minimum value of the given month

e.g.

| date | value |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 2 2024 | 5 |
| Feb 7 2024 | 33 |
| Mar 5 2024 | 7 |
| Jan 3 2024 | 23 |
| Mar 20 2024 | 18 |
| Mar 20 2022 | 1 |

**given: March 2024**

***Result of formula: 7***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

```
=MIN(TOCOL(B2:B7/(TEXT(E2,"me")=TEXT(A2:A7,"me")),2))
```

---

Or, Using `AGGREGATE()`

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,B2:B7/(TEXT(E2,"me")=TEXT(A2:A7,"me")),1)
```

---

Or using `MINIFS()`

```
=MINIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,">="&E2,A2:A7,"<="&EOMONTH(E2,0))
```

---

If those dates are texts formatted with spaces in between, then try the followings as well:

[image]

---

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,B2:B7/(TEXT(--SUBSTITUTE(A2:A7," ",", ",2),"em")=TEXT(--E2,"em")),1)
```

---